# How can I check if my NavigationController subclass has had VC's pushed & popped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

This Apple Doc looks promising, https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontrollerdelegate?language=objc but they are not getting called.

I have a CustomNavigationController that inherits from UINavigationController. I need to know when a VC has been pushed or popped from my CustomNavC.

I can conform to UINavigationControllerDelegate, but this seems to be more for ViewControllers. Not for the CustomNavC to do a `self.delegate = self`.

How can this be achieved?

UPDATE: False alarm. Sorry all. I was testing on device and had OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disabled. The UINavigationControllerDelegate functions work just fine.

Comment: How many navigation controller sublcasss do you have ? If you have only one, you can simply add observer to the navigation stack (viewControllers property) which is an array. And post notification when it is changed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to override the `pushViewController` and `popViewController` methods.

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];

    // Handle push as needed
}
```

There are several `pop...` methods you can override as well.

You may also wish to override the `setViewControllers:animated:` method which is called when the whole stack is replaced.

Overriding these methods leaves the delegate free to be used by other classes.

Comment: Can we add observer to the UINavigationController viewControllers proeprty and observe it when changed ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Possibly. I've never tried to do that so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Please post your own answer instead of using this answer to post your unrelated comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in your `CustomNavigationController` and add these functions:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    }

func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried, however, those function are never called.

Comment: They also exist in Obj-C.

Comment: Do you use a storyboard? If yes, then did you specify your CustomNavigationController class for your navigation controller in your storyboard?